# How do I select the line at the caret in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

I found "Select Word at Caret" in the Edit menu. Is there a way to do similar, but select the entire line?

Comment: You can select entire line pressing `Ctrl` twice and then press `Home`/`End` in recent PhpStorm versions, as explainded in the link similar to that in RANA answer bellow:
[link] https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.1/selecting-text-in-the-editor.html

Comment: If you want to select multiple lines you can hold alt and click at the start of the lines, then press ctrl+c

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you have nothing selected, and press ⌘ + C, PhpStorm will automatically copy the line at the caret. So basically, you don't need the 'Select Line at Caret' action.

Comment: and that's also making the line selected.

Comment: Note, you can also press ⌘ + D (or CTRL + D for Windows) to automatically duplicate the current line as well without selecting any text.

Comment: It's Alt + D fo windows

Answer (score 12):

I found "Select Line at Caret" in Preferences under "Keymap". (And associated it with ⌘-L.)

[image]

Comment: Just want to add that in the current PhpStorm version (2017.3.4) the keymap is still there, but it is unassigned by default, so you have to add your own shortcut.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using **`phpstorm 9`** you can press couple of times **`ctrl + w`** to select the current line. Also it has some other benefits. Check out **`Extending selection`** at [**`https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/selecting-text-in-the-editor.html`**](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/selecting-text-in-the-editor.html) for more details